# How to pass a struct member as a pointer in a function?

Tags: c

The problem is that I have a struct that is member of another (major) struct. I've written a function to clear the first struct (it takes a pointer to struct).

I would like to use that function to clear the struct inside the major structure, but I don't know exactly which is the correct way of doing that.

To explain it better, here is some code:

I have a structure, defined as:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char next;
    unsigned char first;
    unsigned long data[TCP_RX_BUFFER+1]; 
}struct_circ_buff;
```

and a function to clear it:

```
void clearCircularBuffer(volatile struct_circ_buff *circular_buffer)
{
    int i=0;

    for(i=0;i<TCP_RX_BUFFER+1;i++)
        circular_buffer->data[i]=0;

    circular_buffer->first=0;
    circular_buffer->next=0;
}
```

Then, I have another struct which includes `struct_circ_buff`:

```
typedef struct 
{
    volatile unsigned char sensorType;
    volatile uint16_t  sensorFlag;
    volatile struct_circ_buff st_circular_buffer;
}struct_sens;
```

and I would like to write a function that would clean this struct, using the `clearCircularBuffer` function written above. How could I do that?

```
void clear_sensors_struc (volatile struct_sens *sensors_struct)
{

sensors_struct->sensorFlag=0;
sensors_struct->tipoSensor=0;

    //NOW, HOW CAN I USE clearCircularBuffer to clean sensors_struct->                      
    //st_circular_buffer??

    //this way compiles fine, but i don´t think it´s correct
    clearCircularBuffer(&(sensors_struct->st_circular_buffer));

    //this way wouldn´t even compile
    clearCircularBuffer(sensors_struct->st_circular_buffer));
}
```

Finally, I have a variable declared as:

```
struct_sens struct_sensores[MAX_NUMBER_OF_SENSORS];
```

and I would like to write a function that would clean that array of structures...

So how could I use `clear_sensors_struc` function to do that?

```
void clear_sensors_struc_array(struct_sens *sensors_struct)
{
    struct_sens aux_str[MAX_NUMBER_OF_SENSORS];  
    int i=0;    

    for(i=0;i<MAX_NUMBER_OF_SENSORS;i++)
    {         
        clear_sensors_struc(&aux_str[i]);
        *(sensors_struct+i)=aux_str[i];
    }
}
```

Is there any way of doing that without defining an internal struct_sens aux_str?

Comment: `//this way compiles fine, but i don´t think it´s correct` <- Well, it _is_ correct.

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851848/passing-struct-pointer-to-functions-not-working

Comment: Why you don't save a (strcut_circle_buf *) pointer  in struct_sens instead of a struct_circle_buf  . The things goes clear .

Comment: @DanielFischer, thank you for reading and answering! Nisarg: thank you! I had already seen that post and i took some positive things from it but my case was slightly different. LidongGuo: thank you for the suggestion; I´m gonna analyze it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the function `clear_sensors_struc`, it is indeed correct to do:

```
//this way compiles fine, but i don´t think it´s correct
clearCircularBuffer(&(sensors_struct->st_circular_buffer));
```

It's right because (inside function `clear_sensors_struc`):

- **`sensors_struct`**: is a pointer to a struct.
- **`sensors_struct->st_circular_buffer`**: dereferences `sensors_struct` (using `->`) and allows you to access its member `st_circular_buffer`.
- **`&(sensors_struct->st_circular_buffer)`**: is a pointer to the member `st_circular_buffer` of struct `sensors_struct` that happens to be a struct `struct_circ_buff`.

As the function `clearCircularBuffer` requires a pointer, it will compile and work right.

Regarding the function to clean the array of structs, what about this?:

```
void clear_sensors_struc_array(struct_sens *sensors_struct)
{
    int i=0;    

    for(i=0;i<MAX_NUMBER_OF_SENSORS;i++)
    {         
        clear_sensors_struc((sensors_struct+i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nicolas so much for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Per Nicolás' example:

```
clearCircularBuffer(&(sensors_struct->st_circular_buffer));
```

We can directly use

```
clearCircularBuffer(&sensors_struct->st_circular_buffer);
```

Because `->` gets precedence over `&`.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all you have not defined the structures correctly. Define the structures as below:

   ```
   typedef struct one
   {
       unsigned char next;
       unsigned char first;
       unsigned long data[11]; 
   }struct_circ_buff;

   typedef struct two
   {
       volatile unsigned char sensorType;
       volatile int  sensorFlag;
       volatile struct_circ_buff st_circular_buffer;
   }struct_sens;
   ```
2. And you asked:

   > I would like to write a function that would clean this struct, using the `clearCircularBuffer` function written above. How could I do that?`

   You can do it as below:

   ```
   void clear_sensors_struc (volatile struct_sens *sensors_struct)
   {

       int i;

       sensors_struct->sensorFlag=0;
       sensors_struct->sensorType=0;
       sensors_struct->st_circular_buffer.next=0;
       sensors_struct->st_circular_buffer.first=0;

       for(i=0;i<TCP_RX_BUFFER+1;i++)
       {
           sensors_struct->st_circular_buffer.data[i]=0;
       }    
   }
   ```

Comment: Its a good way of cleaning the array of struct_sens, but in this case,I would like to make the most of 'clearCircularBuffer' function. Of course I could do it as you said, but the question was basically about structures and pointers handling.