# Struct field access

Tags: c++, struct

Is the return value of `someStruct.someField` a copy of the field?  If I get a pointer to that value, will the pointer point to the value in the struct or a copied value on the stack?

e.g. Is the following guaranteed(it appears to work in a simple test) to work?

```
struct SomeStruct {
    int someField;
    SomeStruct() : someField(0) {}
}

void func(int* val) {
    *val = 42;
}

SomeStruct someStruct;
func(&(someStruct.someField));

// Is it guaranteed that someStruct.someField == 42?
```

Comment: Yes. You are handing the address of someStruct.someField into func(). So func() dereferences that address and sets the value to SOME_OTHER_INT_VALUE.

Comment: True. THere is no copying of someStruct.someField.

Comment: `someStruct.someField` doesn't return anything, it _is_ the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems legit, see here -

[How to pass a struct member as a pointer in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928123/how-to-pass-a-struct-member-as-a-pointer-in-a-function?rq=1)

If you want to make sure for yourself, you can compile and look at the assembly code, you'll see that the compiler passes the direct address to tha given element, without copying anything "out" of it.

Take for e.g. this code:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} T;

void set(int* c) {
    *c = 0;
}

int main()
{
    T t;
    set(&(t.b));
    set(&(t.c));

    return 0;
}
```

built (with gcc 4.2.2, -O2), and disassembled with objdump, the main function gives:

```
0000000000400500 <main>:
  400500:       53                      push   %rbx
  400501:       48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp     //"allocates" t on the stack
  400505:       48 8d 7c 24 04          lea    0x4(%rsp),%rdi //creates a direct pointer the t.b
  40050a:       e8 e1 ff ff ff          callq  4004f0 <set>
  40050f:       48 8d 7c 24 08          lea    0x8(%rsp),%rdi //creates a direct pointer the t.c
  400514:       e8 d7 ff ff ff          callq  4004f0 <set>
  400519:       8b 44 24 04             mov    0x4(%rsp),%eax
  40051d:       03 44 24 08             add    0x8(%rsp),%eax
  400521:       48 83 c4 10             add    $0x10,%rsp
  400525:       5b                      pop    %rbx
  400526:       c3                      retq

00000000004004f0 <set>:
  4004f0:       c7 07 00 00 00 00       movl   $0x0,(%rdi)
  4004f6:       c3                      retq
```

So the modifying function would write directly into the original struct defined, unless of course at some point along the way you do create a copy of it (which is a common mistake, for example by creating T t2 = t)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that:

1. `SOME_OTHER_INT_VALUE` actually fits in an `int`
2. Compiler doesn't have serious bugs.

then yes.

Comment: So, unlike function calls, struct member access doesn't return a copy?  It's the assignment that performs the copy: `int foo = someStruct.someField;`  foo now has a copy of someStruct.someField correct?

Comment: No, it works because you are passing the ADDRESS of `someStruct.someField` to `func`. If you have `int foo=7;` then `func(&foo);` would also modify `foo`, not a copy of `foo`, because the value you are passing to `func` is the address of something (which is indeed a copy, so if you were to do `val++;` inside `func`, `foo` would still stay in the same place)

Answer (score 0):

When you access a structure's field in that way, you are not calling a method, so that doesn't return anything (and in consequence it can't be a copy).

What you are really doing is to access directly your structure's field, then `SomeStruct.someField` is the current structure's field, you can change it and/or reference it.

In your example

```
SomeStruct someStruct;
func(&(someStruct.someField));
```

, what you are doing is giving a pointer right to your structure's field, so you can do whatever you want with it.